# How does node process gets crashed exactly on Friday midnight with the 'Cannot read property getALPNNegotiatedProtocol of null' error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

Note: This is a react server running on https.

Following error is noticed in the logs. The process crashes exactly on friday during midnight.

_tls_wrap.js:631
this.alpnProtocol = this._handle.getALPNNegotiatedProtocol();
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getALPNNegotiatedProtocol' of null
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:631:36)
at TLSWrap.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:103:9)